# what is the difference between NSURLResponse and NSHTTPURLResponse

Tags: ios, objective-c, response

Pardon me for this silly question but can anybody please tell me what is the difference between NSURLResponse and NSHTTPURLResponse

Comment: I hope AppleDocumentation will tell you. Even if you want to award 15 points then I can copy paste from there...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "NSURLResponse declares the programmatic interface for an object that
>   accesses the response returned by an NSURLRequest instance.
>
> NSURLResponse encapsulates the metadata associated with a URL load in
>   a manner independent of protocol and URL scheme.
>
> An NSHTTPURLResponse object represents a response to an HTTP URL load
>   request. It’s a subclass of NSURLResponse that provides methods for
>   accessing information specific to HTTP protocol responses." *
>
> **Quote taken from the official Apple Developer [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSURLResponse_Class/Reference/Reference.html).*

Comment: Nice answer, but no +1 :) You must have read my comment in question.

Comment: @AnoopVaidya I posted it a few seconds after your comment, but yes, that is understandable so don't worry :)

Answer (score 0):

NSHTTPURLResponse - It returns, The receiver’s HTTP status code.
NSURLResponse - It returns, The receiver’s URL.

For more details you can refer 1.https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLResponse_Class/Reference/Reference.html.
2.https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSHTTPURLResponse_Class/Reference/Reference.html